# Powershell script to check for a text pattern Ignoring the history log

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2012

I'm writing a PowerShell script which will check for the text "error" in a notepad and launch something if the pattern condition satisfies. I wrote the script to do this but the challenge is to make the script ignore what was read already.

Lets say I have a notepad saved log.txt, below script would check for the pattern text "There is a error" and will launch wordpad. I want the script to ignore already read patterns. Scan for only the new ones.

```
if(Select-String -path "C:\Users\dddd\Desktop\error.txt" -pattern "There is a error"){Start-Process wordpad.exe}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I could imagine using an environment variable or a registry key to keep track of where I am in the file, in conjunction with Get-Content to read a file line by line

Comment: Is the log file rotated?

Comment: @BryceMcDonald I'm not sure about using an environment variable/registry key. Any example script?

Comment: Do you have any example text? The only way I could see this working is if there are timestamps you could work around or you have to keep a copy of the file as read at that moment in time and diff when you read the next pass. That could get dicey with large log files.

Comment: I would use a variable to store where you want to begin reading, and then export it with `Export-Clixml` to a file, and read it back the next execution with `Import-Clixml`.  The challenge is going to be to know when the log file has been updated and you need to start over entirely.  If there are dates at the beginning of the log file this might be another value you can store.  Otherwise you'll probably have to rely on the log file's CreationTime (which will be updated if the file is moved, so beware).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The log file gets appended with error message every time a service fails/crashes. Whatsoever the error message it may be, it all starts with "error:" ...ex: "error: Invalid URI in request GET". I want the script to notify or do something based on the latest message ignoring the past ones.???

Comment: @deechris27 I think the concern we have here is that if you aren't rotating your log file, then a script to read it and launch something will be memory inefficient and it won't take long before a script starts causing more errors than the service.  The other concern is that if it *does* rotate then you'll need an easy way to "reset" the counter in your script

Comment: Then store the line number of the last line you read from the file in the registry and continue reading from that offset. Storing a single number in an XML file deems me a bit overkill.

Comment: @BryceMcDonald Not true. Files can be processed line by line with minimal memory impact (using a `StreamReader`), and it's also no problem to skip lines when you know the offset at which you want to continue processing. The problem with not rotating logs is that the log file will continually grow and eventually consume the entire free disk space.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers What you suggested seems feasible for my level of knowledge on powershell. I'll try to store the line number and see if it could be made to work.

Answer (score -1):

I would approach this problem in a couple of steps.  First, I'd need a way to keep track of my progress while reading the file.  In this case, I'm going to use an environment variable, but you'd probably be a little better off using a registry key.  In order to set this variable, we can call the .Net "SetEnvironmentVariable" method:

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ErrorLine", "0", "Machine")`

This starts our environment variable at "0", which we'll use to keep track of the line number of the file we're scanning.

Next, we need to be able to read the content of the file, and compare it to your string.  For this, I like to use a For loop, in conjunction with a cmdlet which would let us view a file line by line.

```
For ($i = $env:ErrorLine, $i -lt ((Get-Content $logPath).Count), $i ++) {
  if ((Get-Content $logPath)[$i] -contains '*error*') {
    do something
  }
  $env:ErrorLine += 1
}
```

Granted, you'll have to do some troubleshooting and you may want to wrap this all in a try{}catch{} block for further error handling, but this ought to get you started.

Comment: `if ((Get-Content $logPath)[$i] -contains '*error*') {` is surely  going to read the _entire_ file again just to use the one line you need and everytime the condition is checked in the for This also means the file will change as this code is executing. If you are going to do this use this there are better ways to get this using linecounts and select-object -index etc. Specifically read the file once.

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways to read the file content, and these solution definitely doesn't scale to large log files.  This script is more or less a starting point for OP to build from.  Feel free to edit if you'd like to make it a more complete solution